# Replace function variables (lodash) with dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, lodash

I'm new to writing JS functions and struggling to make the following use case work:

- Based on the value of the dropdown within a HTML page, change the variable within a lodash function and submit that to display within a HTML div.

I cannot seem to get anything other than a blank output from the following, when I pull the variables `countryA` and `countryB` out of the broader function then it works but not when inside.

Any help much appreciated:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/the_winslet/pen/oNxxaVZ)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Auto populated dropdown</h2>
    
 <form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectCountry1">
  </select>
     <select id="selectCountry2">
  </select>
    <input id="searchCountry" type="button" value="Take me travelling"/>
</form> 
  
    
  <h2>Result</h2>
  <div id="travelResult"></div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
const UK = [
    {id:'GB', name:'Great Britain', QT:'14 Day', info:'visit gov.uk'},
    {id:'CR', name:'Croatia', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
    {id:'EU', name:'European Union', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
    {id:'IRL', name:'Ireland', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'}
 ];
const USA =[
    {id:'USA', name:'USA', QT:'14 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
    {id:'CR', name:'Croatia', QT:'14 Day', info:'visit us.gov.croatia'},
    {id:'IRL', name:'Ireland', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'}
 ];
const EU =[
    {id:'GB', name:'Great Britain', QT:'14 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
    {id:'CR', name:'Croatia', QT:'14 Day', info:'visit us.gov.croatia'},
    {id:'IRL', name:'Ireland', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
    {id:'EU', name:'European Union', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
 ];
const IRL =[
    {id:'GB', name:'Great Britain', QT:'14 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
    {id:'EU', name:'European Union', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'},
    {id:'IRL', name:'Ireland', QT:'0 Day', info:'visit gov.uk/'}
 ];

const options = ["UK", "USA", "EU", "IRL"];

// Function to build a dropdown

var select = document.getElementById("selectCountry1"); 

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
};

var select = document.getElementById("selectCountry2"); 

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
};

// var countryA = UK;
// var countryB = USA;

// Function to compare everything

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("searchCountry").onclick = resultSection;
};

function resultSection() {
  
    var e = document.getElementById("selectCountry1");
    var countryA = e.value;
    console.log(countryA);

    var f = document.getElementById("selectCountry2");
    var countryB = f.value;
    console.log(countryB);

    var result6 = _.intersectionBy(countryA, countryB, 'id');
  
    document.getElementById('travelResult').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result6);
    console.log(result6)
};
```

EDIT: Update: got it working by manually defining the each variable when it gets returned, there's probably a better way of doing this, but it works!

```
    if (countryA === "UK"){
   var firstCountry = UK
 } else if (countryA === "USA") {
   var firstCountry = USA
 } else if (countryA === "EU") {
   var firstCountry = EU
 } else if (countryA === "IRL") {
   var firstCountry = IRL
 } else {
   var firstCountry = "Error"
 };
  
  if (countryB === "UK"){
   var secondCountry = UK
 } else if (countryB === "USA") {
   var secondCountry = USA
 } else if (countryB === "EU") {
   var secondCountry = EU
 } else if (countryB === "IRL") {
   var secondCountry = IRL
 } else {
   var secondCountry = "Error"
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. The options in a select are an HTMLOptionsCollection, but an individual option value e.g. `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` is a string. You can probably do a string comparison on the selected values and not need `_.intersection` instead just using `===`.
2. If you want the selected value of a `<select>` element you can just call `e.value` instead of `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`.
3. _.intersectionBy returns the intersection of two ARRAYS with a given iteratee. Your values need to be arrays so you can wrap them like this:

`var result6 = _.intersectionBy([countryA], [countryB], 'id');`

Also the iteratee is not needed because you are dealing with strings that can be directly compared. This means you can use:

`var result6 = _.intersection([countryA], [countryB]);`

4. Finally you might be conflating the JS array of options with the HTML select options? You would need to take the value in the select and find the entity in your array that corresponds to that option (comparing on value is probably a good way).

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for taking the time to reply.

Really still struggling here - all I want to do is change the _.intersectionBy arrays using a dropdown, no idea why this is so much of a challenge.

Any words I should be using to search for a solution you would recommend?